# Помогите разобраться в коде php, в каждой строке

Tags: php

Логин и пароль к админ панели поменять нужно.

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$enter = $_REQUEST['enter'];

if(isset($enter)){
    $result_user = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `nameuser`='".$name."' AND `passworduser`='".$password."'");
    $res_user_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result_user);
    if($res_user_rows<=0){
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/edit/index.php");
        exit;
    }
    else{
        $res_user = mysqli_fetch_array($result_user, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION['name'] = $res_user['nameuser'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $res_user['passworduser'];      
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$res_user['file']);
        exit;
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: Найдена критическая уязвимость в коде - [SQL инъекция](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name']; // Записываем в переменную name параметр name из запроса
$password = $_REQUEST['password']; // То же самое для password
$enter = $_REQUEST['enter']; // и enter

if(isset($enter)){  // если задана переменная enter
    $result_user = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `nameuser`='".$name."' AND `passworduser`='".$password."'"); // делаем запрос к базе, в котором ищем пользователя с заданными в запросе именем и паролем
    $res_user_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result_user); // записываем количество выданных записей в переменную res_user_rows
    if($res_user_rows<=0){ // если нет результатов
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/edit/index.php"); //редиректим на эту страницу
        exit;
    }
    else{ // иначе
        $res_user = mysqli_fetch_array($result_user, MYSQLI_ASSOC); // разбираем результат запроса к бд
        $_SESSION['name'] = $res_user['nameuser']; // записываем в сессию логин
        $_SESSION['password'] = $res_user['passworduser']; // и пароль
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$res_user['file']); // редиректим на страницу, указанную в таблице пользователей в базе данных
        exit;
    }
}   
?>
```

Чтобы поменять пароль, надо зайти в базу данных (mysql) и изменить там его
Если есть phpmyadmin, то через него
Если нет, то можно поменять следующим запросом:
`UPDATE users SET passworduser="новый пароль" WHERE nameuser="кому менять пароль"`

А вообще, судя по коду, это крайне небезопасно и топорно написанная система, которую, по-хорошему, нужно полностью переписывать.